# A strange type derivation

Tags: typescript

the code is that

```
export interface TTypeOne {
  type: 'one';
  oneProperty: string;
  body: string;
}

export interface TTypeTwo {
  type: 'two';
  twoProperty: string;
  body: string;
}

export type TTotal = TTypeOne[] | TTypeTwo[] | string;

const total: TTotal = [
  {
    type: 'one',
  },
];
```

the result is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYVin.png)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgFXwE8xgB5JPAbwCg44YTgAuOAcgkrYG465PgABSgRSsIqwDOMKMgDmvegCMIAEwlxpspApoBfGjVCRYiFGiy4CxUvgDuEOLXqNSrNjAc8+niMNFojFIy8opwKurB2roGRuDQ8K54hBAwmAA2cAC81kwUwADaALpwAD65tg7FZZohOrw02JzSDKkZrClpmTkFfM70DEzuAmwANHx640XcQA)

if I change TTotal without string

```
export type TTotal = TTypeOne[] | TTypeTwo[]
```

it can work with

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktjax.png)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgFXwE8xgB5JPAbwCg44YTgAuOAcgkrYG465PgABSgRSsIqwDOMKMgDmvegCMIAEwlxpspApoBfGjVCRYiFGiy4CxUvgDuEOLXqNSrNjAc8+niMNFojFIy8opwKurB2roGRuDQ8K54hBAwmAA2cAC81kwUwADaALpwAD65tg7FvDTYnNIMqRmsKWmZOQV8zvQMTO4CbAA0fHrDRdxAA)

How am I supposed to do that with `export type TTotal = TTypeOne[] | TTypeTwo[] | string;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Re *"the result is enter image description here"* and *"in can work with enter image description here"* : Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: *"if I change TTotal without string...it can work with..."* I'm confused, removing `string` **doesn't** make it work, and your image shows an error. What do you mean by "it can work with"? Do you mean "It's showing me an appropriate error for `TTypeOne`?"

Comment: It's worth noting that even with `| string`, if you write out a full version of `TTypeOne` or `TTypeTwo`, it works: https://tsplay.dev/w8Ey4N So the error message you get when you've only done the `type` property isn't ideal, perhaps, but it's correct that there's an error.

Comment: yes , i hope `export type TTotal = TTypeOne[] | TTypeTwo[] | string` can show me  an appropriate error for TTypeOne when i write `const total: TTotal = [
  {
    type: 'one',
  },
];`